# How to make `ir.attachment`, PDF read-only in Odoo V10

Tags: pdf, odoo, open-source, attachment, odoo-10

I have attached `ir.attachment` model with my custom Course structure model. Currently, attachment model has an access to upload any file(doc, pdf, xls etc.)

- Now I want the user to only upload a pdf file.
- Another User will have the preview of that PDF file and he should not be able to download a particular file.

[image: Pdf only]